# Facebook Open Graph Images, HTTP 302 and Cache-Control

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, http-redirect

I kept getting an warning that og:image wasn't the right dimensions from the Facebook debugger even though it was. Facebook kept falling back to my site's logo instead of the image I specified in the og:image meta element.

I figured out that the cause of this issue was because my image URL was redirecting to Amazon Web Services' S3 storage URL, so therefore the URL I provided for my meta element was a page that sent an HTTP 302 status code. I think the reason why Facebook is not following the redirect is because I don't have any "cache-control" headers sent with the redirection response. However, I'm not familiar with how or what headers need to be set. So, what cache-control headers must I set in order for Facebook to be happy?

The reason I use a redirect is so that my image URLs could dynamically create various sizes based on the parameters included in the URL and cache that resized image on S3. I do a redirect instead of sending data because I'd rather use bandwidth on AWS than on my VPS. I'd like to keep this setup if I can.

Thanks for reading. All help is highly appreciated! :)